# What does the "&0xFFFFFFFF" do in this HIDWORD macro

Tags: c++, macros, dword

I needed the HIDWORD macro for a program I'm making and found this one here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/compile.html

What I'm confused about is why there is a `&0xFFFFFFFF` at the end of it?

```
#define HIDWORD(l) ((DWORD)(((DWORDLONG)(l)>>32)&0xFFFFFFFF))
```

How does that modify the output of this macro in any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it has any real effect - the `(DWORD)` cast that
the final operation of the expression will force the result to 32 bits anyway.

The `(DWORDLONG)` cast forces the shift operation to act on an unsigned value, so no 'sign bits' will be shifted into the intermediate result.  However, since the operand could be 64-bits, there might still be non-zero bits at higher locations than bit 31.  The `& 0xFFFFFFFF` operation will zero out those bits, but so would the `(DWORD)` cast.

But it doesn't hurt, either. One could argue that it makes the intent of the macro clearer (except to you, maybe - just kidding!).

Comment: I think it *does* hurt readability. I know casts to unsigned do a well-defined modulus operation. As demonstrated :) below, I don't know (and can guess wrong) why the bitwise AND is there.

Answer (score 1):

<s>It's dealing with possible [sign extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) by explicitly masking out the high-order bits.  Whether your compiler actually *does* sign extension for a right shift of a negative is implementation-defined.</s>

EDIT: Sign extension refers to setting the high-order bits to keep the sign when a number is shifted.

For example:

```
11111110
```

is -2, if we assume it's a 8-bit two's complement number.  If we do a simple [logical shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) right, we get:

```
01111111
```

However, that changes the sign of the number.  Many compilers will do a arithmetic shift, to give:

```
11111111
```

Note that we fill in the most significant bit (it would be more than one for a more complex example) with 1's.

Comment: `DWORD` and `DWORDLONG` are unsigned types, there's no sign extension going on here.

Comment: @Adam, interesting, then I have no idea what the purpose is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those are unsigned types, and assuming `DWORD` is 32 bits and `DWORDLONG` is 64 bits, then technically it doesn't do anything.

Perhaps it's just code left over from copy-and-paste of similar macro for signed types?

Or perhaps one the assumptions I noted doesn't hold.

Cheers & hth.,